# .populate() devuelve null en consulta

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo un problema tengo dos modelos relacionados con mongoose, aquí pongo los dos modelos

**Modelo Request**

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RequestSchema = Schema({
    concept: String,
    description: String,
    amount: Number,
    status: String,
    checked: Boolean,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Request', RequestSchema);
```

**Modelo User**

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    requested: Number,
    checked: Number,
    role: String
});

UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
    var obj = this.toObject();
    delete obj.password;

    return obj;
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

El problema es que al realizar la petición de la lista de todas las requests me las trae correctamente, pero no me realiza el populate, lo devuelve como null, dejo el codigo que uso para la consulta.

```
getRequests: function(req, res) {
        Request.find().populate('user').exec((err, requests) => {
            if(err) {
                res.json(err);
            }

            return res.status(200).send({
                status: 'success',
                requests
            });
        })
    }
```

La respuesta que me devuelve el rest client la siguiente.

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "requests": [
    {
      "_id": "5dd869285abf6533d04484bf",
      "concept": "Gastos generales",
      "description": "Gatos en viaje",
      "amount": 4512,
      "status": "Pendiente",
      "checked": false,
      "user": null,
      "date": "2019-11-22T23:03:04.257Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Ya he intentado utilizar otros metodos y no encuentro la solución, todo me duevuelve null y no he podido identificar ninguna falla en mis modelos.

Comment: Puede que no se haya grabado el id? Revisa con un programa como Robot 3T. Me ha sucedido bastante.

Comment: Lo revisé, con robo3t de hecho coincide el id guardado  en al objeto request con el del user, pero al momento de hacer el populate me devuelve null, incluso ya borré la base de datos e hice nuevos documentos y sigue igual

Comment: Si haces la consulta sin hacer el `populate()` (`Request.find().exec(...);`), ¿también te devuelve `null`?. Porque en teoría todo se ve bien. Aunque yo al crear el `Schema` suelo usar el constructor `new`: `UserSchema = new Schema({...});`. En todo caso, lo que interesa ver es si el campo `user` efectivamente tiene un valor de tipo `ObjectId`. Saludos

Comment: Acaba de sucederme el mismo problema. Por alguna extrania razón me devolvía null. Tuve que eliminar el documento (solo estaba debugueando en una bd local) y al crear otro todo funciono. Hubiera sido bueno copiar ese documento completamente antes de eliminarlo para seguir haciendo pruebas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un disculpa por no haber actualizado de mi situación, la solución fue tan simple que parece increíble, después de revisar todo a detalle y estar 100% seguro de que no había algo con error.
Decidí eliminar la base de datos, crear nuevos documentos y sin ningún problema hizo la consulta correctamente, desconozco cual haya sido el  error pero esa fue mi solución.

Comment: Exactamente me paso eso hace un momento. Es un comportamiento que se me hace extranio. Para este caso en especial creo que es la única solución .

Answer (score 0):

hice pruebas y me resulta de forma correcta el populate, es probable que tengas incorrecto el id en el campo user de la colección Request

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

(async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(
        'mongodb://localhost/test',
        { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false, useUnifiedTopology: true }
    )
        .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB :)'))
        .catch(error => console.error(`Could not connect to MongoDB :( ... ${error}`));

    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var RequestSchema = Schema({
        concept: String,
        description: String,
        amount: Number,
        status: String,
        checked: Boolean,
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    })

    var UserSchema = Schema({
        name: String,
        username: String,
        password: String,
        email: String,
        requested: Number,
        checked: Number,
        role: String
    });

    UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        delete obj.password;

        return obj;
    }

    const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
    const Request = mongoose.model('Request', RequestSchema);

    const id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();
    await User.create({ _id: id, name: "user 1" });
    await Request.create({ description: "request", user: id });

    const result = await Request.find().populate('user');
    console.log(result);
})();
```

Tengo como salida

```
Connected to MongoDB :)
[ { _id: 5ddf5095ee8c5c1b54a8c0ea,
    description: 'request',
    user: { _id: 5ddf5094ee8c5c1b54a8c0e8, name: 'user 1', __v: 0 },
    date: 2019-11-28T04:44:05.036Z,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Comment: Si bien tu código puede funcionar, no responde la pregunta del OP. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podras comentar en cualquier publicación. Por otro lado, el comentario sobre la posibilidad de que el campo `user` de sus documentos no sean de tipo `ObjectId`, ya se lo habían puesto en los comentarios. Saludos

Comment: Si bien lo que dices es correcto, no resolvía mi duda de porque a mi no me funcionaba, pero igualmente gracias!